# Hide/show table rows with a specific class until another row with a different class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have rows I want to show and hide, but only up until the next first-level row. My code is toggling all of the second-level rows instead of the ones up until the next first-level row.

When you click on a row with the class "first-level", I would like every row with the class "second-level" up until the next instance of "first-level" to toggle.

http://jsfiddle.net/a837tc24/

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first-level">
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-level">
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
      <td>First Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-level">
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
      <td>Second Level</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
var firstLevel = $('.first-level')
var secondLevel = $('.second-level')

$(firstLevel).click(function() {
    $(secondLevel).nextUntil(firstLevel).toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Which first level row? You have two.

Comment: Adam remark is important, better use ids in this situation IMHO

Comment: I tried to clarify what I'm trying to do in my original post, hopefully that helps. When a row with .first-level is clicked, I want to show the rows with .second-level, but only up until the next instance of .first-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start at the element clicked:

```
$('.first-level').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.first-level').toggle("slow");       
});
```

Passing in the whole collection just won't work as there is no single point of reference to start from

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a837tc24/1/)**</kbd>